# how to open an new screen from a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created an `ListView` in my XML file but I want to open a new screen from an item on my `ListView`.

I know I must use an `OnItemClickListener` but I don't know what I have to do then.
Can anybody help me please?

My `ListView` in Java:

```
package com.example.listentomusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class March extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.march);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ABOUT"));

            }
        });
    }

}
```

My `ListView` in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/standaard_background" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/maart"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000" />

     <android.support.v7.widget.Space
         android:id="@+id/space1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="15dp" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:entries="@array/songs_march"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
     </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My string array:

```
<string-array name="songs_march">
        <item >1. p!nk - just give me a reason </item>
        <item >2. Bingo Players - Get Up </item>
        <item >3. macklemore  -  thrift shop </item>
        <item >4. troublemaker - olly murs </item>
        <item >5. Netsky - We Can Only Live Today </item>
        <item >6. Dj F.R.A.N.K Feat. Miss Autumn Leaves - Yes You Run </item>
        <item >7. labyrinth – beneath your beautiful </item>
        <item >8. Nicole Scherzinger - Boomerang </item>
        <item >9. DJ Fresh - Gold Dust </item>
        <item >10. Justin Timberlake - suit and tie </item>
        <item >11. cascada – glorious </item>
        <item >12.  DJ Fresh ft Sian Evans - Louder</item>
        <item >13. DJ Fresh ft. Rita Ora - Hot Right Now</item>
        <item >14. one direction - kiss you </item>
        <item >15. Coone - Headbanger </item>
        <item >16. Alicia keys - girl on fire </item>
        <item >17. Skream And Example - Shot Yourself In The Foot Again </item>
        <item >18. Isaac - Ease My Mind</item>
        <item >19.  Headhunterz vs. Psyko Punkz - Disrespect</item>
        <item >20. pitbull - feel this moment </item>
        <item >21. Carrie Underwoods - Two Black Cadillac’s </item>
        <item >22. Alicia keys - Brand New Me </item>
        <item >23. Inna - More Than Friends</item>
        <item >24. Freestylers  -  Cracks (Ft. Belle Humble)(Flux Pavilion Remix)</item>
        <item >25. P!nk - Try</item>
        <item >26. Hien - No More </item>
        <item >27. Xilent - Boss Wave</item>
        <item >28. Christina Aguilera - Just A Fool </item>
        <item >29. Evol - Marina And The Diamond</item>
        <item >30. Kesha - C mon</item>
        <item >31. Matrix And Futurebound  -  Magnetic Eyes</item>
        <item >32. Adele  -  Skyfall  </item>
        <item >33. Baauer - Harlem Shake</item>
        <item >34. Mark With A K - Blow Your Brainz</item>
        <item >35. One Direction - One Way Or Another </item>
        <item >36. Calvin Harris - Drinking From The Bottle </item>
        <item >37. Skrillex And Damian - Make It Bun Dem</item>
        <item >38. Taylor Swift - I Knew You Were Trouble</item>
        <item >39. Coone  -  Monstah</item>
        <item >40. Kelly Clarson - Catch My Breath  </item>


    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Adapter, in your case I recommend to use [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Then the use set the adapter to yout ListView, by list.setAdapter().
After that in onItemClick callback you will get the position of the item that been clicked (starts from 0).
See also that [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/).

Comment: i have read the article but i dont understand it for what i want

Comment: See the second link. And can you be more specific about the screen you want to open is that a new Activity or a Fragment

Comment: I think he wants to expand a list in tree fashion, am I right?